# PHP static variables in double quotes

Tags: php, variables, static, double, quotes

How can I get PHP to evaluate a static variable in double quotes?

I want to do something like this:

```
log("self::$CLASS $METHOD entering");
```

I've tried all sorts of `{}` combos to get the variable value of `self::$CLASS`, but nothing has worked.  I've currently settled with string concatenation but it is a pain to type:

```
log(self::$CLASS . " $METHOD entering");
```

Comment: log(self::$CLASS . " $METHOD entering");
is ONE extra character to type instead of log("self::$CLASS $METHOD entering"); .. this is a pain?

Comment: It's not that bad, but the other one is slightly easier to read and type.  :)  I was just wondering if there was an alternative if you weren't concerned with optimization.

Comment: @Scott: Discouragement is not an answer

Comment: @cmc it's not an answer, it's just *the* answer.

Comment: Sorry, but you can do this. Look at my post here:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773236/proper-way-to-access-a-static-variable-inside-a-string-with-a-heredoc-syntax/39778415#39778415](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8773236/proper-way-to-access-a-static-variable-inside-a-string-with-a-heredoc-syntax/39778415#39778415)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Sorry, you can't do that. It only works for simple expressions. See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex).

Comment: "Since { can not be escaped, this syntax will only be recognised when the $ immediately follows the {."

If I understand this correctly, " {self::$METHOD} " won't work because the $ character must directly follow the left curly brace.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately there is no way how to do this yet. Example in one of answers here will not work, because `{${self::$CLASS}}` will not returns content of `self::$CLASS`, but will returns content of variable with name in `self::$CLASS`.

Here is an example, which does not returns `myvar`, but `aaa`:

```
$myvar = 'aaa';
self::$CLASS = 'myvar';
echo "{${self::$CLASS}}";
```

Answer (score 8):

Use an anonymous identity function stored in a variable. This way you will have `$` immediately after `{`:

`$I = function($v) { return $v; };
$interpolated = "Doing {$I(self::FOO)} with {$I(self::BAR)}";`

(I am using class constants in this example but this will work with static variables too).

Answer (score 4):

I don’t know the answer to your question, but you can show the class name and method using the `__METHOD__` [magic constant](http://php.net/language.constants.predefined).

Comment: Thanks.  This was helpful.  I'm moving over from Java and haven't had a chance to dig into the magic constants.  I'll use these instead of defining class and method variables.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I find it odd that noone has suggested the `[sprintf][1]` function yet.

say:

```
<?php

class Foo {

    public static $a = 'apple';

}
```

you would use it with:

```
echo sprintf( '$a value is %s', Foo::$a );
```

so on your example its:

```
log(
    sprintf ( ' %s $METHOD entering', self::$CLASS )
);
```

Comment: While I agree with you in principle, OP is asking specifically about string interpolation in double quotes. Not `sprintf`.

Comment: @maiorano84 OP said: `I've currently settled with string concatenation but it is a pain to type`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

class test {
    public $static = 'text';
    public $self = __CLASS__;
    // static Method
    static function author() {
        return "Frank Glück";
    }
    // static variable
    static $url = 'https://www.dozent.net';
    public function dothis() {
       $self = __CLASS__;
       echo <<<TEST
           
           {${!${''}=static::author()}} // works
           {$self::author()}            // works
           {$this->self::author()}      // works
           ${!${''}=self::author()}     // works
           
           {${$this->self}}::author()}} // don't works
           ${${self::author()}}         // do/don't works but with notice
           ${@${self::author()}}        // works but with @ !
           
TEST;
    }
}

$test = 'test'; // this is the trick, put the Classname into a variable

echo "{$test::author()} {$$test::$url}";
echo <<<HTML
<div>{$test::author()}</div>
<div>{$$test::$url}</div>
HTML;

$test = new test();
$test->dothis();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//define below
function EXPR($v) { return $v; }
$E = EXPR;

//now you can use it in string
echo "hello - three is equal to $E(1+2)";
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I've accomplished it is by setting a variable to the static class itself:

```
$self = self::class;
```

Then I can interpolate it:

```
$string = "This is: {$self::property}";
```

Answer (score -2):

Just live with the concatenation.  [You'd be surprised how inefficient variable interpolation in strings can be](http://blog.golemon.com/2006/06/how-long-is-piece-of-string.html).

And while this could fall under the umbrella of pre-optimization or micro-optimization, I just don't think you actually gain any elegance in this example.

Personally, if I'm gonna make a tiny optimization of one or the other, and my choices are "faster" and "easier to type" - I'm gonna choose "faster".  Because you only type it a few times, but it's probably going to execute thousands of times.

Comment: Discouragement is not an answer.

Comment: Looks like that permalink is anything but.

Comment: That discussion of string interpolation may not still be true: according to Rasmus Lerdorf (via Twitter), it's a 1 opcode vs tmp var trade-off, and performance is similar.

Comment: article talks claims interpolation is inefficient. provides no benchmarks whatsoever -_-

Answer (score -5):

Yes this can be done:

```
log("{${self::$CLASS}} $METHOD entering");
```

Comment: Yes, it is allowed, but it doesn't achieve the desired effect -- it'll treat `self::$CLASS` as a variable name; so if `self::$CLASS == 'foo'` then you'll end up with `{$foo}`, and not `'foo'` like you might be expecting.