# Static variable string parsing in PHP

Tags: php, string, parsing, variables

Pretty straightforward; I've read through the docs but perhaps I'm just a tad confused by the explanation.

```
class Test{
    public static $var = 'world';
}

echo "hello {Test::$var}"; // only parses $var in current scope, which is empty
```

Is there any way to achieve the desired functionality here? I'm starting to guess no, as I've tried a number of permutations with no success.

*Clarification*: I'm trying to achieve this with PHP's variable parsing, not concatenation. Obviously I'll resort to concatenation if the desired method is not possible, though I'm hoping it is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Variable parsing in PHPs double quoted strings only works for "*variable expressions*". And these must always start with the byte sequence `{$`. Your reference to a static identifier however starts with `{T` hencewhy PHP parses towards the next `$` in your double quotes and ignores `Test::`

You need to utilize some cheat codes there. Either use a NOP wrapper function:

```
$html = "htmlentities";
print "Hello {$html(Test::$var)}";
```

Or pre-define the class name as variable:

```
$Test = "Test";
print "Hello {$Test::$var}";
```

I'm afraid there's no native way to accomplish this otherwise.

Comment: Thanks **mario**; I was afraid of that; the lack of native support for my desired functionality. I'll have to hack around to get something close.

Answer (score 1):

This works with the string concatenation operator ( . )

```
echo "hello ".Test::$var;
```

**EDIT**

> Note: Functions, method calls, static
>   class variables, and class constants
>   inside {$} work since PHP 5. However,
>   the value accessed will be interpreted
>   as the name of a variable in the scope
>   in which the string is defined. Using
>   single curly braces ({}) will not work
>   for accessing the return values of
>   functions or methods or the values of
>   class constants or static class
>   variables.

[Source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)  Via [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267093/php-static-variables-in-double-quotes/1267167#1267167)

Comment: Thanks **Gazler**; I don't want concatenation though, trying to take advantage of variable parsing.

Comment: I do not believe that is possible.  Please see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267093/php-static-variables-in-double-quotes  Especially the link posted as the top answer, which I have quoted in my edits.

Answer (score 0):

You can always break the echo up into the smaller pieces.

```
class Test{
    public static $var = 'world';
}

echo "hello ", Test::$var;
```