# Proper way to access a static variable inside a string with a heredoc syntax?

Tags: php, string, heredoc

Lets say I have a static variable called $_staticVar in my class which I am trying to access like this. The variable has a member `aString` which has the string value of `"my static variable"`

```
    echo <<<eos

    <br/>This is the content of my static variable, 
    self::$_staticVar->$aString
    which is not getting accessed properly in heredoc syntax. <br/>

eos;
```

Output:

> Notice: Undefined variable: _staticVar in /path/to/file.php on line some_line_number
>   
>   <br/>This is the content of my static variable, 
>   self::->my static variable, 
>   which is not getting accessed properly in heredoc syntax.<br/>

The [PHP<sup>docs</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) for [`heredoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) doesn't say anything about this.

---

I have tried this:

```
    echo <<<eos

    <br/>This is the content of my static variable,<br/>
    {${self::$_staticVar->$aString}}<br/>
    which is not getting accessed properly in heredoc syntax. <br/>

eos;
```

and it does not work.
Output:

> Notice: Undefined variable: _staticVar in /path/to/file.php on line some_line_number
>   <br/>This is the content of my static variable,
>    
>   which is not getting accessed properly in heredoc syntax.<br/>

---

This is my PHP setting:

> display_startup_errors = on
>   display_errors = On
>   error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT

Comment: I didn't downvote but try to provide a more functional example. Reading all of this "something" and "somevar" is really dry, confusing and difficult to answer even for the most experienced of developers! Just a tip :)

Comment: @Kieran I will change it with some other string. Point taken. :)

Comment: Thanks. I have restored balance with a +1

Answer (score 4):

I'm fairly certain you must use a local or imported variable for string interpolation. The easiest solution? Why, make it local of course:

```
    $_staticVar = self::$_staticVar; // or did you mean self::_staticVar? Not too clear on that.

    echo <<<eos

    <br/>Something {$_staticVar->something} more of something <br/>

eos;
```

---

As for the reasons your examples didn't work:

```
    echo <<<eos

    <br/>Something self::$_staticVar->{$something} more of something <br/>

eos;
```

Interpolates undefined variables `$something` and `$_staticVar`, which results in an empty string and a notice.

```
    echo <<<eos

    <br/>Something {${self::$$_staticVar->{$something}}} more of something <br/>

eos;
```

Interpolates the value of something that definitely doesn't exist and never will and it's all really confusing but you know it doesn't work.

Comment: I know that I can make it a local. The point is whether there is a method to do without making it local.  :)

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey: No. You can't. Give up.

Comment: Because, I do not see anywhere mentioned that it cannot be done!

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey: It's mentioned in my answer :) Seriously, the docs for interpolation mention that it must begin with a `$` to be counted. Otherwise, [you get an unexpected T_PAMAAYIM_NEUKODTAYIM](http://codepad.org/Tmck3KLB).

Comment: I think that there is no any solution else substitution of the static variable value outside the string and assign it in local variable starts with `$`

Answer (score 3):

You can do show at this sample class to show how to access/call a static method or attribute from inside a string.

You must store the classname inside a variable, so you can access classelements over this variable and yes you can access static variables and static methods.

```
<?php

class test {
    private $static = 'test';
    // static Method
    static function author() {
        return "Frank Glück";
    }
    // static variable
    static $url = 'http://www.dozent.net';
    public function dothis() {
       $self = __CLASS__;
       echo <<<TEST
           {${$this->self}}::author()}} // don't works
           {${!${''}=static::author()}} // works
           {$self::author()} // works
TEST;
    }
}

$test = 'test'; // this is the trick, put the Classname into a variable

echo "{$test::author()} {$$test::$url}";
echo <<<HTML
<div>{$test::author()}</div>
<div>{$$test::$url}</div>
HTML;
```