# using static::member->method inside HEREDOC

Tags: php, heredoc

```
    static public function toolBar()
{
    var_dump(static::$_lang);
    var_dump(static::$_lang->getVal('Index'));
    return <<< EOC
    <a href="index.php">{${static::$_lang->getVal('Index')}}</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
    <a href="?view=login">{${static::$_lang->getVal('Login')}}</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;     
EOC;
}
```

The Expression {${static::$_lang->getVal('Index')}} return nothing
instead of the string

There is any workaround for this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does your `var_dump()` return?

Comment: var_dump(static::$_lang); -> lang Object  var_dump(static::$_lang->getVal('Index')); -> 'Index Page'

Comment: Have you tried `{static::$_lang->getVal('Index')}` ?

Comment: Yep, it refers to static as string. returns '{static::('Index')}'

Comment: Here > http://stackoverflow.com/a/8773260/67332 > the answer owner writes that this is not possible...