# PHP: display static variable inside string

Tags: php, string, oop

How can I display "static variable" inside string: something like this

```
class test
{
    public static $static_var = 10;
    public function name()
    {
        echo "You have {self::$static_var}"; //You have 10
    }
}
```

also tried: `echo "You have {${self::$static_var}}";`
but seems not working too,

I knew about close quotes: `echo "You have ".self::$static_var;`
but is there a way with braces "{}" ?

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP static variables in double quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267093/php-static-variables-in-double-quotes)

Comment: Wondering if there is a way, to embed static variables in SQL queries, in comfortable way in read and write,

Comment: @EladBernardHaviv I see *the $ character must directly follow the left curly brace* in comment of the accepted answer of duplicated question, is it true? Because I don't see clear explanation of this in doc.

Comment: Can't you put the static variable outside of the quotes: echo "You have ".self::$static_var;

Comment: Actually, is pretty clearly stated in the docs, if you follow the link from the accepted answer: _Since { can not be escaped, this syntax will only be recognised when the $ immediately follows the {. Use {\$ to get a literal {$._