# Trouble using PHP complex (curly) syntax with static variables

Tags: php

I'm trying to use the PHP curly string syntax to pull out some static variables.  Here's a quick test class:

```
class asdf{
    public static $variable = 'foo@';

    public static function getValue() {
        return "{asdf::$variable}bar.com";
    }
}
```

I've tried several variations, some of which (like `"${asdf::$variable}"`)  give me the result back as a string, which then gets parsed back as a lookup.  So, I know something there is mostly working.

And for edification, I'm expecting something like 'foo@bar.com' when I call the function.

I expect that it is a syntax issue, but I couldn't find anything useful at the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).  Or maybe it is a deficiency, as I know that many people avoid statics as much as possible.

Comment: As stated at the bottom of the Complex syntax `Using single curly braces ({}) will not work for accessing the return values of functions or methods or the values of class constants or static class variables.` Where you are attempting to access a static class variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP static variables in double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267093/php-static-variables-in-double-quotes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is simply not [possible](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex).

> Functions, method calls, static class variables, and class constants
>   inside {$} work since PHP 5. However, the value accessed will be
>   interpreted as the name of a variable in the scope in which the string
>   is defined. Using single curly braces ({}) will not work for accessing
>   the return values of functions or methods or the values of class
>   constants or static class variables.

The easiest way around would be to just move the var access outside the string.

```
class asdf{
    public static $variable = 'foo@';

    public static function getValue() {
        return asdf::$variable . 'bar.com';
    }
}
```

doing this, you could even use the variable var syntax, if you need to

```
class asdf{
    public static $variable = 'foo@';

    public static function getValue($var = "variable") {
        return asdf::$$var . 'bar.com';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed that paragraph.  I already just did some string concatenation, just wanted to make sure I wasn't crazy.