# How can i call static php variable?

Tags: php, static-methods

i want  to know  how  to insert : self::$tag between <> , thanks

i tried  <{self::$tag}> but it does not function  .

```
<?php 
class model {
    public static $tag = "p" ;

    private static function surround($xx){
        return "<self::$tag>".$xx." </self::$tag>" ;
    }  //here is the problem    

    public static function label($xx){
        return self::surround("<label>".$xx."</label>") ;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP static variables in double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267093/php-static-variables-in-double-quotes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close. Only the string concatenation is wrong. 
Try this:

```
return "<".self::$tag.">".$xx." </".self::$tag.">" ;
```